# findAll Events returning strange class in ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm not sure why, but i'm receiving this strange class in my findAll call:

```
__ember1443850972614: "ember455"
__ember_meta__: Object
__nextSuper: undefined
content: (...)
get content: GETTER_FUNCTION()
set content: SETTER_FUNCTION(value)
isFulfilled: true
__proto__: Class
```

That's all my code, from the server to the client:

EventModel in the server:

```
var EventSchema = mongoose.model('EventSchema', {
  type: {
    type: String,
    "default": 'event'
  },
  attributes: {
    date: Date,
    description: String,
    hiw: Object,
    hour: Date,
    meeting: String,
    men: Number,
    name: String,
    title: String,
    women: Number,
    created_at: Date,
    is_active: {
      type: Boolean,
      "default": false
    },
    updated_at: Date
  }
});
```

My app:

```
  window.SiteApp = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
  });
```

My REST Adapter and Serializer:

```
  SiteApp.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: '_id'
  });

  SiteApp.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
  });
```

My routes:

```
SiteApp.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('events', {
      path: '/'
    });
  });
```

My Events route:

```
 SiteApp.EventsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
      return this.store.findAll('events');
    }
  });
```

My Event Model:

```
  SiteApp.Event = DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string'),

    attributes: {
      date: DS.attr('date'),
      description: DS.attr('string'),
      hiw: DS.attr(),
      hour: DS.attr('date'),
      meeting: DS.attr('string'),
      men: DS.attr('number'),
      name: DS.attr('string'),
      title: DS.attr('string'),
      women: DS.attr('number'),
      created_at: DS.attr('date'),
      is_active: DS.attr('boolean'),
      updated_at: DS.attr('date')
    }
  });
```

And the JSON (is not complete):

```
{
  events: [{
    _id: "55f660bdd80a0fd2e298f333",
    attributes: {
      description: "test",
      name: "name",
      is_active: false
    },
    type: "event"
  }, {
    _id: "560f5da1e4b056e1540d1016",
    attributes: {
      description: "test",
      name: "name",
      is_active: false
    },
    type: "event"
  }]
}
```

All the code in: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYMzQo

Please, i'm very frustrated, i'm stuck on this for at least 5 days, somebody give me a light!!

Comment: This is one of Ember classes, probably Ember.Array. What's your problem with it?

Comment: to be more precious, it's a [DS.PromiseArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseArray.html), and this is ok

Comment: is not ok, i want the json data..

Comment: the response should be the jSON, that's wrong..

Comment: [DS.store](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html) was created to store data, and operate with it. It loads data from server __or other storage, depending on adapter__, creates instances of DS.Model and stores them in memory. Because different types of storage can be used, it can't return JSON. It returns an object, containing instances of models. You need to use methods of [Ember.Array](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html) to get your data.

Comment: If you just want to display data to user, you just need to use [{{#each}} block](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/) in template.

Comment: I get it now! WOW!!! OK!! THANK YOU. Could you elaborate as answer to win points??

Comment: Coud i give me a answer to other doubt? The attributes in the event model in the client, should be wrapped in a attributes object, or its not necessary?

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't understand

Comment: I'm sorry, my native language is not english. I want know if I should register the attributes in EventModel (client) surrounded by an attributes object, as I am already doing, or if this is not necessary.

Comment: If you are talking about `DS.attr()`, it is better to use it, however I don't know for sure what will happen if it will be omitted. I guess ember will not extract model properties from server response.

Comment: As [documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/defining-models/#toc_defining-attributes) says, "Attributes are used when turning the JSON payload returned from your server into a record, and when serializing a record to save back to the server after it has been modified."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DS.store](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html) was created to store data, and operate with it. It loads data from server or other storage, depending on adapter, creates instances of DS.Model and stores them in memory. Because different types of storage can be used, it can't return JSON. It returns an object, containing instances of models. You need to use methods of [Ember.Array](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html) to get your data. Here is a small example:

```
 SiteApp.EventsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
      return this.store.findAll('events').then(function(events){
        events.forEach(function (item, index, enumerable) {
          console.log(item.get('attributes.title'));
        });
      });
    }
  });
```

If you just want to display data to user, you just need to use [{{#each}}](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/) block in template:

```
{{#each model as |event|}}
  <div>{{event.attributes.title}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: In my case i should access the title like {{ event.attributes.title }}, yes?